# Periodically download a file from web in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, file-download

I have a HTTP URL of a file. Is there a simple way to schedule a periodic download of that file (say, every 24 hours) to a certain location on disk, thus overwriting the previous version?

Possibly by using Windows scheduler, and not having to install yet another bloated program just to do this simple task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use PowerShell to perform this action just enter the following in to task scheduler.

```
powershell.Exe -command "& {$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient;$client.DownloadFile('http://www.domain.com/file.mp3','c:\temp\file.mp3')}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using wget for windows and enter it's path into your system environmental variables.

It's very lightweight and it won't be a bad utility for your system if it's something you want.

http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/wget/

Comment: This would be my choice. Using WGET is very easy to use and yes, you can add a scheduled task to run it now and then, invisibly in the background.