# In Powershell, is it possible to define a filename that changes every time the command is run?

Tags: command-line, powershell

For a dissertation Im trying to repeatedly download an XML through an API. It has to be done every hour or three hours for a long period of time.

I've found a few ways that I can download something once, for instance with PowerShell:

```
powershell.Exe -command "& {$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient;$client.DownloadFile('http://exampleapi.uk?key=examplekey','C:\location\APIcall.xml')}"
```

I got this from [Periodically download a file from web in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/252005/periodically-download-a-file-from-web-in-windows-7/252038#252038?newreg=017858e3c271406c93a2fda3e0b1f343)

However, is it possible to set a dynamic filename so that every download gets a new name and files don't get overwritten? Ideally, they would get a timestamp in their name, but as long as no data is overwritten I'll be happy.

Note: Im a GIS student with some SQL and C++ experience but nothing advanced. I cant use answers that require hours on hours of study just to understand if it can be done, like libcurl or gnuwin, I just need to solve this and move on with using the data for a mapping project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a file path and filename before calling the `DownloadFile()` method easily using `Join-Path`.

Something like

```
powershell.exe -command "& {$fileOut = Join-Path -Path 'C:\location' -ChildPath ('APIcall_{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH_mm_ss}.xml' -f (Get-Date))
                            $client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
                            $client.DownloadFile('http://exampleapi.uk?key=examplekey', $fileOut)}"
```

Here I use the `-f` [Format operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#format-operator--f) to convert the DateTime **object** from `Get-Date` into a timestamp **string** `{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH_mm_ss}`.  Of course, you can format the date differently, but make sure it does not contain invalid filename characters like `:`, `/` or `\`

Comment: Wow thats exactly it!!! Thank you very much, Ill tweak the stamp to suit my subsequent processing, but my data store is already filling up. Excellent!

Answer (score 0):

[Get-Date](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date) will return the current data & time as a *DateTime* type. There are a variety of [pre-defined](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) or [custom](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) formats you can apply.

Here's an example usingthe pre-deifned "s" (sortable)
format using the `-f` format operator:

```
$BaseName = 'MyBaseName'
$ThisRunName = '{0}_{1:s}' -f $BaseName , ( Get-Date )
$ThisRunName
```

Output:

```
PS C:\> $BaseName = 'MyBaseName'
>> $ThisRunName = '{0}_{1:s}' -f $BaseName , ( Get-Date )
>> $ThisRunName
MyBaseName_2021-05-05T13:01:30
PS C:\>\
```

---

Low vision here -- didn't even notice the colons ( illegal in filenames )  in the Sortable format. Here's a better example using a custom format string. Dropped the seconds from the time as the O.P. did state every few hours:

```
$BaseName = 'MyBaseName'
$ThisRunName = '{0}_{1:yyMMdd_HHmm}' -f $BaseName , ( Get-Date )
$ThisRunName
```

Output:

```
PS C:\> $BaseName = 'MyBaseName'
>> $ThisRunName = '{0}_{1:yyMMdd_HHmm}' -f $BaseName , ( Get-Date )
>> $ThisRunName
MyBaseName_210505_2239
PS C:\>
```

Comment: But that won't do as filename because of the invalid characters in there..

Comment: Then you use a custom format. There was no formatted code, limitations, or preferred format given by the O.P. All you would need to do is change the format specifer.